# androidstudio fails to install gradle-2.2.1-all.zip (ubuntu)

Tags: android-studio, gradle

wnloading http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip

2021-05-13 16:44:18,034 [   6328]   WARN - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: Could not install Gradle distribution from 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip'. (602 ms)
2021-05-13 16:44:18,034 [   6328]   WARN - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Could not install Gradle distribution from 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip'.
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.issue.BuildIssueException: Could not install Gradle distribution from 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip'.
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip

I can download the file just fine, but android-studio fails to do so..

Comment: All Gradle downloads have moved to https.  Did you configure it to use http? 1.12 is quite old too...(over 7 years old!!!)

Comment: Thank you. You made me seek thru the old source files, and there I found a gradle URL that was HTTP. 
Correcting that solved the installation-failure.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to edit the gradle-wrapper.properties among the app source.  tim_yates led me to discover the solution.